# how to increase download speed while downloading mp4 video through php script

Tags: php, download

I'm using a script to download video, but it take lot of time to download. Are there any processes or other scripts that could help me?

```
// set headers
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: $mtype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$asfname\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);

// download
// @readfile($file_path);
$file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
if ($file) {
  while(!feof($file)) {

    print(fread($file, 1024*100));
    flush();
    if (connection_status()!=0) {
      @fclose($file);
      die();
    }
  }
  @fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [readfile()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function (as you originally had) will allow you to spool directly from the file to output, rather than using a chunking loop and printing as you're doing. So why have you chosen to do this chunk loop?

Answer (score 0):

As above, [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is one way.

The other, even more preferred method depends on your webserver. NginX, Lighttpd and there's also a module for Apache, allows you to pass a header with a filepath/name to the server, and it will send the file directly from the server itself, and so not need to use PHP resources to do it.  If thats not possible, then readfile() is the best you probably have - if you can't just give someone a direct URL to download it.